# Opening a .txt file with fopen creates extra blank lines

Tags: php, vb.net, fopen

I am trying to generate a string in vb.net, which I then want to send to my server, to a .php file which should append that string to a .txt file. There are multiple lines in the string. The string reaches php file correctly. However, during the writing to the .txt file, the php creates extra blank lines, which I don't want.

What I want in my .txt file:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

What I get:

```
line1

line2

line3
```

I tried changing the parameters of the fopen call (adding b in the arguments to force the binary mode), but it didn't help. I also tried replacing vbNewLine with "\n" and "\r\n" in the vb.net code to separate lines in the string, but unfortunately, that isn't recognized, and gets written to the .txt file like

```
line1 \r\n line2 \r\n line3
```

Here is my vb.net application code:

```
   function sendStringToServer()
      Dim stringToSend as String
      stringToSend = "line1" & vbNewline
      stringToSend &= "line2" & vbNewline
      stringToSend &= "line3"

      Dim wc As New WebClient
      wc.Headers("content-type") = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      Dim response As String = wc.UploadString("http://www.example.com/uploaddata.php", "data=" & data)
      MessageBox.Show(response)
```

(Note that the response is correct, no extra blank lines.)
And there is the upploaddata.php code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["data"]))
    {
        echo($_POST["data"]);
        $data=$_POST['data'];
        $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'ab');
        fwrite($fp, $data);
        fclose($fp);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: No data!";
    }
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: after being asked to do a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, I am pasting the code and the results:

in vb.net application, the Sub that sends a string to uploaddata.php:

```
   function sendStringToServer()
      Dim stringToSend as String
      stringToSend = "line1" & vbNewline & "line2" & vbNewline & "line3"

      Dim wc As New WebClient
      wc.Headers("content-type") = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      Dim response As String = wc.UploadString("http://www.example.com/uploaddata.php", "data=" & data)
      MessageBox.Show(response)
```

The entire uploaddata.php contents:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["data"]))
    {
        var_dump($_POST['data']);
        $data=$_POST['data'];
        file_put_contents('data.txt', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: No data!";
    }
?>
```

The contents of data.txt after calling the sendStringToServer() in vb.net application:

```
line1

line2

line3
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Emma, there are multiple ways to write this, and I tried the way you suggested, but I still get the same result.

Comment: Side note: Do not use `"\r"` and `"\n"` in VB.NET; they're treated as literal strings. Instead, use the constants `vbCr` and `vbLf` respectively.

Comment: PHP won't write anything you don't ask it to. That line is coming from your VB code. Try `var_dump($_POST['data'])` instead of `echo`. Also, you could use `file_put_contents` to write to file with one line of code.

Comment: miken32, I tried var_dump - the response is still correct (no empty lines). I also tried file_put_contents - unfortunately, I still get empty lines in the .txt file.

Comment: Create a [mcve]; include the actual data you're sending, the actual code, and the actual output from PHP when you run it.

Comment: miken32, I did as you said (hopefully I got it all right). Please take a look at my edit of the original post.

Comment: You didn't need to just duplicate the existing code. 1) that isn't the VB code you used `("data=" & data)` 2) what's the output from `var_dump` look like?

Comment: And do note that you're appending to the file with `fopen`. Maybe try deleting the file and starting over. If that is actually the VB code you were using, you're going to find an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions, one of which will hopefully solve your problem. Instead of using `vbNewLine` (which is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbnewline?view=netframework-4.7.2) BTW) try [using `vbLf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vblf?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead. Ensure your values are [trimmed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.trim?view=netframework-4.7.2) of leading and trailing whitespace before using them (I assume your actual code will be using variables.) Also your string needs to be properly [URL encoded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.7.2) before being sent as POST data.

```
function sendStringToServer()
  Dim stringToSend as String
  stringToSend = Trim("line1") & vbLf
  stringToSend &= Trim("line2") & vbLf
  stringToSend &= Trim("line3")
  stringToSend = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(stringToSend)

  Dim wc As New WebClient
  wc.Headers("content-type") = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  Dim response As String = wc.UploadString("http://www.example.com/uploaddata.php", "data=" & stringToSend)
  MessageBox.Show(response)
```

On the PHP side, you can simplify your code with `file_put_contents` instead of the old `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fclose` trio.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["data"])) {
        echo($_POST["data"]);
        file_put_contents("data.txt", $_POST["data"], FILE_APPEND);
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: No data!";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, miken32!! Changing vbNewLine to vbLf fixed it. I have no idea why vbNewLine caused this extra empty line issue, but I'll be sure to use vbLf from now on. Many thanks!

Comment: @JustinasRubinovas : The reason you see blank lines is that whatever you viewed or output the .txt to treated the CR character as a separate line break as well. On Windows the standard line ending is a composite character of CR + LF, whereas on Linux/Unix systems (on which most PHP servers run) only use LF. It still odd though because it should be compatible with CR + LF and shouldn't treat it as _two_ separate lines.

Comment: @JustinasRubinovas : **TL;DR:** Use `vbLf` (if necessary) when you are exchanging strings with non-Windows systems and use [`Environment.NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline) when operating only on the current system and/or the same application.

Comment: Thanks, Vincent, but why can't I use vbLf inside the current operating system/same application as well?

Comment: @JustinasRubinovas : Because as I said on Windows line endings are supposed to be both CR + LF. If you use only LF then applications like Notepad will treat it as if there are _**no**_ line endings, and thus display no new lines (the exact opposite of the problem you have now). This is why you should rather use `Environment.NewLine` unless you are transferring the string to an external service (like PHP), because `Environment.NewLine` adapts to the current system and uses CR + LF if run on Windows and LF if run on Mac OS, Linux, etc.